# Is my Roth-IRA still valid after if the business no longer exists?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, small-business

I have a Roth-IRA from my company that is no longer in business. Is it still valid for me to contribute to it or do I need to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Roth-IRA or for that matter a regular IRA is generally not connected to your place of employment.

Now a 401(k) is linked to your place of employment. If the business no longer exists, they should have turned over the 401K. The US department of Labor has information regarding [plans that have been abandoned](http://www.dol.gov/ebsa/faqs/faq-abplanreg.html).

> **I suspect my plan is abandoned, but I have never received a notice of
>   plan termination. How could I find out if a QTA has elected to
>   terminate and wind up my 401(k) pension plan?**
>
> EBSA has developed an Abandoned Plan searchable database to help
>   participants and beneficiaries find out if a particular plan is in the
>   process of being, or has been, terminated. The site is searchable by
>   plan name or employer name and will provide the name and contact
>   information for the QTA, if one exists.  If you do not have access to
>   a computer to conduct the search, you may contact one of EBSA’s
>   Benefits Advisors to assist you by calling toll-free, 1.866.444.EBSA
>   (3272).

Answer (score 0):

In general, Roth IRAs, are associated with the individual.  Unlike 401(k)s for which the business holds the retirement account in the name of the individual.  So, although the company may have helped you set up the Roth it is in your name and you can continue to contribute to it.  Wikipedia has some [helpful information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_401(k)_and_IRA_accounts) here.

It should be noted, however, that sometimes businesses set up special deals with retirement service companies or brokers that hold Roth IRAs so you should check with the particular company/broker that holds your Roth.